# React tsx function is not receiving value

Tags: reactjs, tsx

I'm using a component that is a function that return a navbar depending if the user is logging or not, for this I need pass a parameter to this function.

The index.js always call to NavBar class

```
    render() {
    const isLogged: boolean = true as boolean;
    console.log("F isLogged " + isLogged);
    
    return (  
      <>
      <NavbarComponent {...false}/>
      <h2>It is {this.state.data}.</h2>
      </>
    );
  }
```

This NavBar class call to the problematic component, the NavbarComponent

```
export default function NavbarComponent(isLogged: boolean) {
  console.log("isLogged " + (isLogged as boolean));
  ...
    <div>
        <main
        className={clsx(classes.content, {
          [classes.contentShift]: open,
        })} />
        {isLogged == true ? 
          renderMenuLogged:
          renderMenuLogin}
    </div>
```

```
[Log] F isLogged true (2.chunk.js, line 63)
[Log] F isLogged true (2.chunk.js, line 63)
[Log] isLogged [object Object] (2.chunk.js, line 272)
[Log] isLogged [object Object] (2.chunk.js, line 272)
[Log] F isLogged true (2.chunk.js, line 63)
[Log] F isLogged true (2.chunk.js, line 63)
[Log] isLogged [object Object] (2.chunk.js, line 272)
[Log] isLogged [object Object] (2.chunk.js, line 272)
```

Whats happen on log, when log the F isLogged the return a true, but when log the isLogged of NavBar return a [Object Object], when use debug mode and check what have this var the var is empty, it's like {...false} never go to NavbarComponent(isLogged: boolean)... Any ideas? :(

Comment: The parameter of a component function is the props object. Which is what you get instead of isLogged.

Comment: `false` is a JS keyword, you can't use it as a property name. You are spreading the value `false` onto your conponent which doesn't make sense. The `isLogged` inside the Navbar is the props object, not a boolean. You need to destructure the props to access them, but even if you did that, you are still not passing `isLogged` to the navbar component.

Comment: You are not using Typescript  FunctionComponent<T> which would catch your error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer:

You are missing `{` a `}` in the argument declaration. Note that `isLogged` is not the argument of your functional component. The `props` object is the argument:

```
export default function NavbarComponent({ isLogged: boolean }) {
```

The long answer:

To properly catch errors with typescript, you should start declaring your components with correct types:

```
type NavbarProps = {
  isLogged: boolean
}

const NavbarComponent: React.FunctionComponent<NavbarProps> = ({ isLogged }) => {
  ...
};

export default NavbarComponent;
```

That would catch your error right away.